# Can pass login page with wrong password/username AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, authentication

If type the username or password once wrong and change manually the URL to my home GUI, I get access to it without any authentication.

I can't explain why :/

this is my app.js, where all the routing happens and a fiddle with my controller and my html data :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // declare modules
    angular.module('Authentication', []);
    angular.module('Home', ['naif.base64', 'ngFileSaver']);

    //dependecies of the module 
    angular.module('JMeterGui', ['Authentication','Home','ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
    //configure the module
    .config(config)
    //configure the start of the module
    .run(run);

    //dependencies of the config module
    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$qProvider'];
    //configure routing depends on the actual URL
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $qProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }

    //dependecies of the run module
        run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies', '$http'];
        function run($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
            // keep user logged in after page refresh
            $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
            if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; 
            }

            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                // redirect to login page if not logged in
                var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login']) === -1;
                var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
                if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            });
        }
})()
```

[my fiddle with controller and html](https://jsfiddle.net/mquwg94t/4/)

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Your link to the fiddle does not work.

Comment: @Korte sorry, i have fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
   //Prevent default
   event.preventDefault();
   $location.path('/login');
}
```

Comment: hi,

i have try it, but still the problem :/

Comment: i can't explain that, only if i type the username or password wrong i get access to my home Gui.. if i try change the URL manually without type the username or password, everything works fine